# bash: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

i am trying to install phone gap on Ubuntu. I followed all the necessary steps and successfully installed the android sdk on Ubuntu. but when I type android in the terminal it shows permission denied. How do i change the permission. 
The error is:

```
bash: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied
```

Comment: If you type `ls -l /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android` does this begin with `-rwxr-xr-x`? The 'x' are important.

Comment: If not, do: `chmod a+x /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android` and try again.

Comment: You may have to use sudo to execute the chmod.

Answer (score 14):

Set the permissions using chmod exec'd using sudo

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

Comment: Helped me after so much time struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Simply fix the rights

```
chmod +x /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

and enjoy.

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android’: Operation not permitted.

Answer (score -1):

Hit <kbd>CTRL + ALT + T</kbd> , then write :

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

this will grant you all your necessary action in android