# permission denied error while trying to insttall android sdk build tools

Tags: android, cordova

My production project is in such a way that it need to have Android sdk 21 to work with cordova. But when I tried to download the build package 21.1.2 from android sdk manager, it says permission is denied.

```
URL not found: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/temp/build-tools_r21.1.2-linux.zip (Permission denied)
```

I get the Android sdk manager by typing android in my command line. Now when I type sudo android . It says command not found. Also is there any way that I could just install 21 version of the build package

Comment: Make sure the user has admin privilege

Comment: If you're launching the SDK manager from a command line, precede this line with `sudo`

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641514/bash-usr-local-android-sdk-linux-tools-android-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these steps.

Switch to root user by typing `su` or `sudo -i`

then run `android` and install the packages.

see this question for why it is giving command not found
[Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)